# How do I search for Q&As regarding this C++ template syntax?

Tags: discussion

I found some code in GCC's standard library 6.1.0 (`bits/shared_ptr.h`) that I don't understand: `template<blah, typename = blah>`

```
namespace std {

  template<typename _Tp>
    class shared_ptr : public __shared_ptr<_Tp>
    {
      template<typename _Ptr>
    using _Convertible
      = typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Ptr, _Tp*>::value>::type;

    public:
      template<typename _Tp1, typename = _Convertible<_Tp1*>>
                           // ^^^^^^^^^^^ What is this syntax: "typename ="?
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Tp1>& __r) noexcept
        : __shared_ptr<_Tp>(__r) { }
    }
}
```

I assume there are already existing questions around this C++ template syntax, but I cannot think of a good search term.  My *Google-Fu* fails me again.

Can someone either give me a good search term or a Q&A on this matter?

(And if there is no existing Q&As on this matter, I will ask a new question.)

Comment: To spare you the search, it's a default template argument. Just like default function parameters. Maybe you can search on that.

Comment: "c++ template typename" ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments

Comment: If you are curious about syntax then a good reference like [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a great place to start.  genpfault linked to the exact place in his/her comment but all you need to do is search "templates" in the search on the page and it will get you there.  You can do the same for standard functions, containers, and language features.  It is a very handy site.